# How to build request for oAuth2 using nodejs ?"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement oAuth2.0 using nodejs , the approach i have in mind by calling first token endpoint and get the token and then use the token to call the actual endpoint to get the data. i am getting token undefined from the backend.

I need help with below scenario what would be best approach to get oAuth2 token for the backend.

main.js

```
function getAllEODList() {

        const options = {

                    "tokenHost": "https://test/oauth2/token",
                    "addAuthTokenTo": "header",
                    "body": {
                       "scope": "APPPII APPPHI",
                       "grant_type": "client_credentials"
                    },
                    "credentials": {
                       "sdk_voyage": {
                          "clientId": "xyz",
                          "clientSecret": "zbc"
                       }
                    },
                    "authorizationMethod": "header/form"
                 
        }
       const promise =  do_something(options)
              .then(function(my_data){
                       const options2 = {
                             url: 'https://apiwebsite.com',
                             headers: {'authorization' : 'Bearer ' + my_data, 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
                             port: '443',
                             path: '/users',
                             method: 'GET'
                             }
                      do_something_else(options2)
                                     .then(function(my_other_data){
                                               //do stuff with my_other_data
                                                }
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by how you phrased your question and your code doesn't make sense, but the gist of what I'm getting is you want to get a token from the backend and you're trying to implement OAuth 2.0, so I'll try to answer that question in the context of Node.js as best I can. As an aside, when you say: "calling first token endpoint and get the token and then use the token to call the actual endpoint to get the data.", this is not conformant to the recommended protocol that OAuth 2.0 specifies, and is in fact insecure. I will first explain what you should do and then how to implement it.

I'll answer this question from the perspective of implementing the Authorization Code grant type, defined in [RFC6749](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749), which is what is recommended to be used (with PKCE as defined by [RFC6736](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636), but I'll leave off PKCE in this answer as it'll just complicate things. Feel free to read up on the linked RFC though.

RFC6749 defines two authorization server endpoints to be used in the Authorization Code grant type: the Authorization Endpoint and the Token Endpoint. This is described in Section 3 of RFC6749 but I'll summarize it:

The Authorization endpoint is used by the client to obtain authorization, in this case, a *code*. This code is something that you need to generate server side and store somehow. The code should have high entropy, and should be valid for a period of no more than 10 minutes, as defined by the specification. You may accomplish this by using the `crypto` module to generate some random bytes and cache it somehow on your backend for 10 minutes.

The token endpoint is the endpoint used by the client to obtain a *token*, and a valid *code* must be presented in order to acquire a token.

Now let's view the entire flow:

Client clicks *login* button on the client side frontend. Client is redirected to the authorization server. The uri is very important, and should look like:

http://auth.example.com/authorize?grant_type=code&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback&scope=openid scope1 scope2&client_id=example-client-id&state=some-opaque-value.

This url isn't URL encoded but you get my point (the spaces would be replaced with proper url-safe characters). The URL contains five things:

1. grant_type=code
2. redirect_uri=the client's redirect uri
3. scope= a set of scopes separated by spaces
4. client_id= your client id
5. state= some random string with a large amount of entropy that is generated client side before any request is sent.

The authorization server should validate this URL and make sure it has the necessary query parameters, and should not serve any requests if it is not, as per [RFC6749 Section 4.1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.1)

If the URL is valid, the Authz should present a login or signup page, and authenticate the end-user's credentials. If they are incorrect, the Authz should NOT redirect them to the redirect_uri but instead display some kind of error flash message. However, if the client authenticates successfully, the Authz should **generate a code**, i.e. in your case, you could use the Node.js `crypto` module to generate a random string. This should be appended to the redirect uri along with the state that the client previously presented <-- this is important!, i.e. your Authz should redirect the end-user back to something that looks like:

http://example.com/callback?code=your-generated-code&state=the-state-that-was-presented

Once this happens, the client should validate that the **state** parameter in the url is the same as the one that it originally created. If it is not valid, the code should not be used --> someone is attacking you or you have an error. If the state parameter is correct, then the **code** that you received in that redirect url should now be used to acquire a *token*, at the token endpoint that I explained earlier.

Your request to your token endpoint at the authorization server could look something like this:

http://oauth.example.com/token?grant_type=token&code=the-code-you-received&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback&client_id=example-client-id

Your Authz should now validate that

1. the code presented is valid
2. the redirect_uri is valid
3. the client_id is valid
4. the code has not expired (they should have a max ttl of 10 minutes)

If this all checks out, the Authz should create and generate a token, typically a JSON Web Token (JWT) containing the following claims, as specified in [RFC9068](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9068). To spare you some time, those claims should be:

- iss
- exp
- aud
- sub
- client_id
- iat
- jti

Now that your client has a token, they should be able to use it to authenticate against your api.

Okay now that we've seen the flow, here are a couple pseudocode templates that you could maybe try to implement, but there are a lot of factors that could affect this, for example, whether your client is public or confidential (public clients don't get refresh tokens unless they are **rotated** and PKCE is used --> see [Auth0: Authorization Code Flow with PKCE](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce)

Your Authz could have an file that looks like this:

```js
// forgive me if my node.js isn't perfect, it's been a while since I've 
// written it but you get the gist:

import { Router } from 'express'

const router = Router();

//authorization endpoint
router.route('/authorize').get(async(req,res,next)=> {
    if(!validateRequestQuery(req.query)) return res.status(401).json({valid-oauth-error-msg-here});
    const state = req.query.state;
    const code: string = generateAuthorizationCode();
    const cacheSuccess = await cacheCodeForTenMinutes();
    if(!cacheSuccess) return res.status(500).json('valid-oauth-error-here');
    const callbackUri = `http://example.com/callback?code=${code}&state=${state}`;
    res.redirect(callbackUri);
  }
)
//once the above function is called, the client needs to validate the state //it sends back!

//token endpoint
router.route('/token').get(async(req, res, next){
   if(!validateTokenRequestQuery()) return a valid oauth error
   const code = req.query.code
   const isCodeValid = await checkCache(code);
   if(!isCodeValid) return a valid oauth error
   const accessToken = new Token(); // <--create a valid Access Token here
   const refreshToken = new Token(accessToken); // if your client is confidential or you are using refresh token rotation and PKCE!
   const idToken = new IdToken() // <-- if the openid scope is included
  return res.status(200).json('accesstoken, idtoken'); 
  // NEVER SEND REFRESH TOKEN TO FRONTEND. it is highly insecure. store it 
  // server side instead.
});
```

If you have any questions feel free to respond. This is a very complicated topic and some of what I said may have been too vague, so please ask me to clarify if that is the case.